# Different values weibull pdf

Tags: python, scipy, weibull

I was wondering why the values of weibull pdf with the prebuilt function dweibull.pdf are more or less the half they should be

I did a test. For the same x I created the weibull pdf for A=10 and K=2 twice, one by writing myself the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) and the other one with the prebuilt function of dweibull.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import exponweib,dweibull
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
K=2.0
A=10.0
x=np.arange(0.,20.,1)
#own function
def weib(data,a,k):
    return (k / a) * (data / a)**(k - 1) * np.exp(-(data / a)**k)

pdf1=weib(x,A,K) 
print sum(pdf1)

#prebuilt function            
dist=dweibull(K,1,A)
pdf2=dist.pdf(x)
print sum(pdf2)

f=plt.figure()
suba=f.add_subplot(121)
suba.plot(x,pdf1)
suba.set_title('pdf dweibull')
subb=f.add_subplot(122)
subb.plot(x,pdf2)
subb.set_title('pdf own function')
f.show()
```

It seems with dweibull the pdf values are the half but that this is wrong as the summation should be in total 1 and not aroung 0.5 as it is with dweibull. By writing myself the formula the summation is around 1[[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`scipy.stats.dweibull`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.dweibull.html) implements the *double* Weibull distribution.  Its support is the real line.  Your function `weib` corresponds to the PDF of scipy's [`weibull_min`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.weibull_min.html) distribution.

Compare your function `weib` to `weibull_min.pdf`:

```
In [128]: from scipy.stats import weibull_min

In [129]: x = np.arange(0, 20, 1.0)

In [130]: K = 2.0

In [131]: A = 10.0
```

Your implementation:

```
In [132]: weib(x, A, K)
Out[132]: 
array([ 0.        ,  0.019801  ,  0.03843158,  0.05483587,  0.0681715 ,
        0.07788008,  0.08372116,  0.0857677 ,  0.08436679,  0.08007445,
        0.07357589,  0.0656034 ,  0.05686266,  0.04797508,  0.03944036,
        0.03161977,  0.02473752,  0.01889591,  0.014099  ,  0.0102797 ])
```

`scipy.stats.weibull_min.pdf`:

```
In [133]: weibull_min.pdf(x, K, scale=A)
Out[133]: 
array([ 0.        ,  0.019801  ,  0.03843158,  0.05483587,  0.0681715 ,
        0.07788008,  0.08372116,  0.0857677 ,  0.08436679,  0.08007445,
        0.07357589,  0.0656034 ,  0.05686266,  0.04797508,  0.03944036,
        0.03161977,  0.02473752,  0.01889591,  0.014099  ,  0.0102797 ])
```

---

By the way, there is a mistake in this line of your code:

```
dist=dweibull(K,1,A)
```

The order of the parameters is `shape, location, scale`, so you are setting the location parameter to 1.  That's why the values in your second plot are shifted by one.  That line should have been

```
dist = dweibull(K, 0, A)
```